# Hbase countRow Nullpointer exception at validateArgAndGetPB

Tags: java, hadoop, nullpointerexception, hbase, bigdata

Hello I'm working with Hbase.
I want to count Rows of my table, so I used AggregationClient.rowCount()

```
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    AggregationClient aggregationClient = new AggregationClient(conf);
    HTable htable=new HTable(conf,Bytes.toBytes("comment"));
    Scan scan =  new  Scan();
    scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("user"));
    try{
        long  rowCount = aggregationClient.rowCount( htable ,  null , scan);
        System.out.println("Row Count : "+rowCount);

    }catch(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However I met null point exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregationClient.validateArgAndGetPB(AggregationClient.java:804)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregationClient.rowCount(AggregationClient.java:306)
>       at com.naver.hbase.Main.countRows(Main.java:131)
>       at com.naver.hbase.Main.main(Main.java:58)

How can I solve it?

Comment: can you add the *aggregationClient* code aswell please?

Comment: I used Hbase aggregationClient class

Comment: https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-endpoint/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/coprocessor/AggregationClient.java

Answer (score 1):

I`ve recently came across the same problem, solved it by providing *ColumnInterpreter* to *rowCount*. Here is code:

```
ColumnInterpreter ci = new LongColumnInterpreter();
long  rowCount = aggregationClient.rowCount(htable,  ci, scan);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, rowCount methods need 3 parameters

```
long rowCount(final Table table, final ColumnInterpreter<R, S, P, Q, T> ci, final Scan scan) throws Throwable {
```

which calls then

```
final AggregateRequest requestArg = validateArgAndGetPB(scan, ci, false);
```

you are passing `ci = null` , the problem is there

Comment: I didn't understand what to put for that argument. Can you explain what I should put in?

Comment: I followed this code https://github.com/Kuntal-G/BigData-Analytics/blob/master/hbase-coprocessor/src/org/hbase/aggregation/example/HBaseAggregationClient.java